# Manipulating an expression to prove an identity

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to calculate the coefficient of the following expression in two different ways to prove the identity.

Expression: $[x^n](1-x^2)^{-k}(1-x)^{-k}$

Identity to prove: $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{n-1}\binom{2k+i-1}{i}\binom{n+k-i-1}{n-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}{\floor {n/2}}} \binom {k+i-1}{i}\binom{n+k-2i-1}{n-2i}$

---

My work:

$\begin{align} (1-x^2)^{-k}(1-x)^{-k} 
& = (\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{i+k-1}{i}x^{2i})(\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{l+k-1}{l}x^l) \\
& = \sum_{i\ge0}(\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{l+k-1}{l}x^l)\binom{i+k-1}{i}x^{2i} \\
& = \sum_{i\ge0}\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{l+k-1}{l}\binom{i+k-1}{i}x^{2i+l}
\end{align}$

After this I tried substituting a new dummy variable in the summation $m=2i+l$ or $l=m-2i$ but it got very messy with my summation constraints and knowing what to change and what to leave. Also, I'm not sure if there is different steps I need to take right from the beginning to prove the left side of the identity (assuming my steps will take me to the right side).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Note that $$[x^n](1-x^2)^{-k}(1-x)^{-k}=[x^n](1+x)^{-k}(1-x)^{-2k}.$$
Moreover, 
\begin{align} [x^n](1-x^2)^{-k}(1-x)^{-k} 
&= [x^n](\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{i+k-1}{i}x^{2i})(\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{l+k-1}{l}x^l)\\
&=\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{i+k-1}{i}\binom{(n-2i)+k-1}{n-2i}.
\end{align} 
which is the RHS of your identity.

On the other hand,
\begin{align} [x^n](1-x)^{-2k}(1+x)^{-k}
&= [x^n](\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{i+2k-1}{i}x^{i})(\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{l+k-1}{l}(-x)^l)\\
&=\sum_{i\ge0}\binom{i+2k-1}{i}\binom{(n-i)+k-1}{n-i}(-1)^{n-i}.
\end{align} 
which is the LHS of your identity (there is a little typo there, the exponent of $-1$ is $n-i$ and not $n-1$).

P.S. As regards the summation constraints remind that $\binom{n}{i}=0$ for $n>0$ and $i>n$ or $i<0$.

Comment: How did you get the last line from the line before it? Thank you!

Comment: @mhlzzz In the product of the two sums we collects the product of the coefficients of $x^{2i}$  and $x^l$ such that $2i+l=n$, that is $l=n-2i$. Is it clear now?